# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (x_1+x_2+...+x_n)/n= \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need help with this exercise:
Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ that verifies $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = +\infty$$
Now prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}n= +\infty$$

Also I need to find an example that the converse does not apply.

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Please insert some [MathJax commands](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (backslashes and curly brackets are your friends). This is borderline unreadable. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Cesàro summation of a sequence divergent to infinity divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836226/is-the-ces%c3%a0ro-sumation-of-series-divergent-to-infinity-divergent)

Comment: For a counter-example of the converse choose any sequence $x_n \to \infty$ and then set every second element to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M>0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, there exists $N>0$ such that
$$ x_n\ge 4M \text{ for }n> N. $$
For fixed $N$, since
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}=0 $$
there is $N_1>N$ such that, when $n>N_1$,
$$ \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots x_{N}}{n}+M>0. $$
So, for $n>\max\{2N,N_1\}$, one has
\begin{eqnarray} 
&&\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_n}{n}\\
&=&\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}+\frac{x_{N+1}+x_{N+2}+\cdots x_{n}}{n} \\
&\ge&\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}+\frac{n-N}{n}\cdot4M\\
&\ge&\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}+\frac12\cdot4M\\
&\ge&M.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_n}{n}=\infty. $$

Comment: I understand that know. What about to find an example that the converse does not apply?

Comment: Using argument by contradiction will get the result.

Comment: Hello! Why do you specify that $N_1>N$? Since the sequence $\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}$ tends to $0$, there is some $N_1$ such that for $n>N_1$, we have $-M<\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+ x_{N}}{n}<M$, right? I don't see why we need $N_1>N$.

Comment: The reason we need $N_1>N$ is based on $\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N}n$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, for any $N>0$ we need to show that there is $M$ such that for $n>M$ you have $\mu_n>N$. WLOG assume all the $x_i>0$ as a finite set of negatives won't affect the limit at all. Let $M',N'$ be the constants we have for $\{x_n\}$ (i.e. for all $n>M'$ we have $x_n>N'$) then so long as $n>M'$ we have

$$\mu_n={x_1+\ldots+x_n\over n}\ge {(n-M')N'\over n}$$

If we just go to $n>2M'$, then we have

$$\mu_n>{1\over 2}N'$$

which is what we needed to show.

The converse is clearly false, let $\{x_n\}$ be such that $x_{2n}=n$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$. Then $\mu_{2n}={n(n+1)\over 4n}={n+1\over 4}$ but clearly the limit of the $x_i$ does not exist.

Comment: I understand that. What about to find an example, that converse does not apply?

Comment: I already have a counterexample to the converse in my answer, did you read the second part?