Construct a divergent series whose average of partial sums converges
Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a divergent series, and let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$.
Define $\sigma_n = \frac{S_1 + S_2 + \cdots + S_n}{n}$. Select $a_n$ such that the infinite series diverges, but the sequence $\sigma_n$ converges.
I have tried several different things, but no matter how slowly I let the series for $a_n$ diverge, its average partial sums still seems to grow without bound.
Any solution outlines or hints would be much appreciated. I am unsure if I am allowed to use divergent alternating series to solve this, so answers that avoid the use of alternating series (if possible) are preferred.

Did you try $a_n = (-1)^n$?

@Sam if it turns out I am allowed to use alternating series, then this should satisfy my question. I will close my question until I have confirmed that information.
If I may ask, how did you find the post that you linked? I searched for all the same keywords present in that post and it never came across my search results.

See this link for series which diverges to infinity: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1836246/694899. This has happened with me as well. I just try to use a lot of keywords.
